# Transformar lista de strings em lista de tuplas

Tags: python, string, lista, tuple

Tenho isto:

```
l=['Car 8', 'Bike 5', 'Train 10']
```

e gostaria de ter algo como isto:

```
[('Car','8'), ('Bike','5'), ('Train','10')]
```

Como podia fazer para transformar uma lista de strings em algo como uma lista de tuplas de strings?

Comment: José, existe a possibilidade de haver espaços em branco no texto, algo como `'Other Bike 5'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) pode fazer:

```
>>> [tuple(x.split(' ')) for x in l]
>>> [('Car', '8'), ('Bike', '5'), ('Train', '10')]
```

A cada elemento é feito `split` com espaço e sobre o resultado do `split`, que é uma lista, é construída a tupla utilizando `tuple`.

[Veja o código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/s897b9)